# spark streaming: mapping points into queue

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am new to spark streaming and I can't understand how map works. I want to enqueue some points from a stream after I pass it from a constructor so what I wrote is:

```
val data = inp.flatMap(_.split(","))
val points = data.map(_.toDouble)
val queue: Queue[Point] = new Queue[Point]
points.foreachRDD(rdd => {
rdd.map(x => queue.enqueue(new Point(x,1)))
})
```

when I print the size of the queue is always zero.

Answer (score 0):

All transformations in Spark are lazy and they do not compute their results right away. Instead, they just remember the transformations applied to some base dataset. The transformations are only computed when an action requires a result to be returned to the driver program.

Since you are applying ***map*** function here , its a lazily evaluated and will not be computed.Instead, a DAG is built. This will be evaluated only when an action is called. You might wanna try collect or any other actions to materialize this.

You can read more about this here.Its kinda old but informative.
https://training.databricks.com/visualapi.pdf